# Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit installed but hangs during boot on dual-boot Win7 Pro 64-bit system

Tags: installation, dual-boot, 13.04, boot-repair

My Win7 Pro 64-bit system (8GB, 1TB, 3.2ghz Intel Xeon w3565) was working fine. I wanted to add Ubuntu 13.04. I booted from USB, selected try me, everything booted fine and I got my Unity desktop. I finally installed Ubuntu alongside Win7.

Grub comes up with Ubuntu as the default. I scroll down and Windows boots fine. I reboot and let it try Ubuntu. Nothing. The screen goes black and I have a blinking cursor in the top left. It hangs. I reboot and go to advanced options and choose recovery mode.

I get output but again, it hangs. The last few lines I see are (times are truncated by me)...

```
[0.51] ACPI: PowerButton [PWRF]
[0.51] ACPI: Requesting acpi_cpufreq
[1.49] Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 3.199.999 MHz.
[1.49] Switching to clocksource tsc
```

Any ideas on how to fix? Or even how to just uninstall Ubuntu altogether? I tried the os-uninstaller, but that doesn't seem to work [exist] with a 13.04 usb stick. I guess I can try putting an older version of ubuntu on the stick and see if I can install to the os-uninstaller.

[edit] I successfully uninstalled 13.04 by booting linux-secure-12.10-64bit.iso from USB and running os-uninstall.

I also tried the boot-repair tool, but all that did was add another Win7 entry into the grub menu (one for dev/sda1 and another for dev/sda2, and both work and boot to Win7... http://paste.ubuntu.com/5616403).

From what I can tell, I don't have UEFI, just normal BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of things, you did well to uninstall the (broken) install.
If your computer is back to normal, ie. you have the Win 7 boot entry (which boots you into win 7 error-free) on boot and no spurious linux/ubuntu problems coming up then I suggest BEFORE installing ubuntu of ANY kind again, or any O/S for that matter, to PARTITION your harddrive.

You say you have 1TB, which is more than enough to divide into a decent set of neat partitions, so windows is allowed, say 200Gig, Ubuntu is allowed 200Gig, maybe another 100Gig partition for data (music / videos etc.) ,a temp partition for incoming (downloading) files, 200Gig for installed Windows programs and another 100 installation files - which would leave 100 GIg for a recycler partition - These O/S' / data partitions  would also need backup partitions if possible - the amounts are really up to you.

For  advice on partitioning your hard drive, there  will be many people who do things different ways, Then you'll need space for backups etc. and also you need to think ahead about what happens if a part of you harddrive fails or if you need to only partially delete a broken install but keep the installation files so try to keep the partitions not overly large and roughly the same kind of sizes yet also keep them more than large enough to accommodate any updates (it's a balancing trick). A couple of 500Meg (1/2 Gig) Linux-Swap partitions are nice as well.

Give your O/S es the amount of room they need corresponding to how much you expect to be using them and how big and what programs you will be running, but you can always change the size of them relatively easily as long as the partitions are kept defragmented regularly!

Ex. my Pc has only 80 Gigs so I have 37Gig for Win7 64-bit (I'm already running low on room), 30Gig for Ubuntu 32bit 12.04 (also a tight squeeze), 12 Gig for playing with (I'm currently using it for Android Virualbox project work but might stick ubuntu 64 bit 13.04 server on there) and two 500Meg swap partitions. Like I say, 80Gig is really too small these days, so with 1TB I would definitely look at giving at least 100Gigs to each of my partitions and then if needing to, merging them together at a later stage.

Bear in mind that mindows formats it's partitions as NTFS and ubuntu formats its ones as  ext4 filesystems which are not mutually compatible... ubuntu can "read" wndows, but not vice-versa. So - like I say - draw a plan up dividing up your 1TB (on paper) then take it from there, using "gparted" during a live CD boot of ubuntu. This will make sure your 1TB is just how you need it!

The reason I say all this is because I suspect this is why you are having problems with your dual-boot... Two operating systems can sit side-by-side but having everything on a single 1TB partition is a bit drastic.. what if something goes wrong with windows? Keeping everything "protected" keeps buffers in  your data so you can manipulate it and install / uninstall / backup a whole lot more easily.

So, boot your Ubuntu Live CD, run "gparted" and shrink your main 1TB partition to whatever you want for your main win 7 partition. Then "slice" up (still using gparted) the rest of your drive for your Ubuntu / data / backup / temp / swap etc. etc. files... make sure you have the main win 7 partition as master boot, and make sure you don't leave any "unallocated" (wasted) space knocking about! Read up on how others utilize their space for different O/S first!

Practice makes perfect, chances are you will have to play about with gparted a bit before you are happy with your setup.

Then to try installing Ubuntu - boot the Live CD and install it to one of your ext4-formatted partitions as the place to put it. You WILL most likely lose Grub, but this isn't a major problem. As long as you have a working Live CD of Ubuntu to boot into and an internet connection, just burn a CD of "Super Grub" beforehand (or Boot-repair CD). This is a boot-CD which will basically detect all the operating systems on your 1TB Drive and let you boot into any one of them (as long as they are working!).

Once you are into your Ubuntu O/S, then you can repair your grub(2) onto to your main Ubuntu partition (ie. put the menu list back to normal with win7 Ubuntu debug memtest options etc. etc.) via the Live CD by downloading grub2 - `sudo apt-get install grub2` in terminal -

Then to put it back on to your main Ubuntu partition, mount your main Ubuntu partition and use "grub-install" to put grub there in your /root/boot folder. Once this is done, use "upgrade-grub" to make grub (or grub2) include an option for EVERY O/S residing on your PC - then you will be able to boot up without the LiveCD, the menu will have all your options back. Sounds hard but there's plenty of info online about how to go about this.

So Windows has it's own boot loader (the MBR on the windows partition) AND you will have ONE (up-to-date) grub2 - this will be containing details of every O/S on your 1TB, placed in your main Ubuntu partition at the /root/boot/grub folder. Sometimes it's confusing if you have lots of partitions / operating systems, but it goes like this...

win7 -- boots using it's own MBR (Master Boot Record)
Ubuntu -- boots using Grub2 --

So your main (first) boot will call up the Ubuntu partition's grub(2)
This grub2 will contain the boot information for your win7 MBR and any other O/S's - giving you EVERY option for booting off your hard-drive.

Sorry to ramble but that would help your computing life big-time, just getting used to playing around with these concepts until they work for you...